# How to run a script every hour that has some commands which need password?

Tags: bash, sudo, gnu-screen

I am working on cloud desktop and trying to execute ./parseScript.sh which has following command:

I want to call this script every hour which I am doing by using following commands:

```
Step 1. Connect to your cloud desktop using ssh.
Step 2. Run these commands:
% screen
% while true; do ./parseScript.sh; sleep 3600; done
Step 3. Close the window with the running command.
Step 4. (same as Step 1) Connect to your cloud desktop using ssh.
Step 5. Run this command: screen -R. You will get back to the session you left in step 3.
```

Now the problem is that in my script I have 1 command mentioned above, which has to be executed using sudo -u identmon, hence this will ask for password every time, Is there anyway to run this script every hour except manually?

Comment: Do you have ssh access?

Comment: yes I do have it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add `NOPASSWD` option your sudors file you can check here https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

That said be carefull you are adding a no password sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the scripts using [expect feature](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) of bash. Store the password in some variable. [Expect utility](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) will automatically supply the password to scripts while running.